# Combine Leaflet.TextPath and a customized popup function into one leaflet layer

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet

I have this script working as I want to, but I'd like to know how I would combine the Leaflet layers into one to make it a better script, without using a grouplayer:

```
var namelayer= L.geoJson(parcels, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.setText(feature.properties.NAME, {attributes: {'fontsize': '15', 'fill': 'white'}, offset: 5}) },
        style: {
            weight: 1,
            color: 'blue' , 
            attributes: {'font-size': '24'}      
    }
}).addTo(map);


function POPUP(feature, layer) {
    var popupContent = "<h3>Info</h3>"
        + '</b><br />' + 'area: ' + feature.properties.m2 + ' m2';
    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
};


var popuplayer = L.geoJson(parcels, { 
    onEachFeature: POPUP,
    style: {
        weight: 1,
        color: 'blue' , 
        attributes: {'font-size': '24'}      
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

The variable parcels is retrieved from a json file with data of the property features.

The setText part is code from: [this Leaflet plugin](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.TextPath)

I am trying to  integrate the variable namelayer into the popuplayer, by copying this line of code into the POPUP function

```
layer.setText(feature.properties.NAME, {attributes: {'fontsize': '15', 'fill': 'white'}, offset: 5}) }
```

This results in this code, and is not working:

```
function POPUP(feature, layer) {
    var popupContent = "<h3>Info</h3>" + '</b><br />' + 'area: ' + feature.properties.m2 + ' m2';
    layer.setText(feature.properties.NAME, {attributes: {'font-size': '15', 'fill': 'white'}, offset: 5}) };
    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
};


var popuplayer = L.geoJson(parcels, { onEachFeature: POPUP,
    style: {
        weight: 1,
        color: 'blue' , 
        attributes: {'font-size': '24'}      
    }
}).addTo(map)
```

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong or forgetting?

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'Not working'. Error messages, what do you get, what did you expect?

Comment: I saw no layer appear on my leaflet map. But I already found the answer myself, it was the last  } in the line of code: layer.setText(feature.properties.NAME, {attributes: {'font-size': '15', 'fill': 'white'}, offset: 5}) };

Comment: Thanks @Jieter because of your comment about error messages I found it by looking in inspector in my browser, I did that before but looked over it I guess.

Comment: Nice, glad it works. Not sure if you already use an editor with color coding, but you should try that if not.